# protect sharepoint calendar events after approved/rejected

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I have sharepoint foundation 2013. Users can add events to calendar with approval workflow. When manager approve event it is showed in calendar. After that manager can edit or even delete events.

It is posible to protect event against modifications by manager after apporve/reject? (only site administrator can do it)

Answer (score 0):

if you running workflow under administrator (and creating the calendar record under it) [you can use app step and publish WF under SCA] you can set Manager permissions (and all permissions) on Calendar list to READ. Cause he need only permissions to Workflow Tasks for approving task.

Or you can create your own permission level, where you create copy from *Contribute permission level* andremove the options, after this use this permission level for the Managers.

1. Go To **Site Colllection**
2. Open **Site Settings** and Permissions
3. In ribbon select **Permission Levels**
4. Open **Contribute** and click on **Copy Permission Level**
5. Remove **Edit Items** and **Delete Items** choices
6. **Save as New** Permission Level
7. **Set this permission** to the Calendar list

[image]

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Calendar records are created by users. Workflow initiator is "System Account". When I turn off 'edit elemens' option for manager group 'approve elements' option is turned off by system. This two options are connected.

Comment: Hi, answer edited, you can create your own permission level and disable the choices for edit and deletion (use Contribute as template) added manual

Comment: Hi, I allready have my own permisions level. I need it for manager group. When "approve items" is not selected no one from group can approve/reject. But when I turn off "edit items" it turn off also "approve items"

Comment: but you should use this permission level on "Calendar List" not on "Workflow Task list" do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more approach you may want to consider.

1. Create two Calendars i.e. One for submitting the events(CalA) and another one to display approved events(CalB).
2. You can distribute the ***Create New event*** URL of calendar CalA with everyone.
3. You can now, build the workflow on the calendar CalA and send the approval request to the manager.
4. Once the event is approved, create a new event in the CalB based on the information from the CalA and you can choose to delete the approved event from CalA
5. If the event is rejected, then you can send an email to requester and then delete the event from CalA
6. Ensure to provide RO access to everyone on CalB so that no one can add/update/delete the created events.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I thought about this solution but I looking for something simpler. Why workflow cannot protect something, change permissions for element?